# How to get header name in autogenerated GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to get the header name in an autogenerated `GridView` in a `Button` click event.header column must not be same..all the time..

So depending upon the column header we have to process further. Please help to find the column header.

We are finding the rowindex by below code

```
var rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
```

like this. So how to find the column index of a `GridView` when a link button is clicked inside the `GridView`?

'

```
string dt1 = txtFromDate.Text;
     string d1, d5 = "", d3 = "", d4 = "", date, d6, service_Date;
    if (dt1 != "")
    {
        d1 = dt1;
        if (d1.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] word = d1.Split('.');
            d5 = word[0];
            d3 = word[1];
            d4 = word[2];
        }
        else if (d1.Contains("-"))
        {
            string[] word = d1.Split('-');
            d5 = word[0];
            d3 = word[1];
            d4 = word[2];
        }
        else if (d1.Contains("/"))
        {
            string[] word = d1.Split('/');
            d5 = word[0];
            d3 = word[1];
            d4 = word[2];
        }

        date = d4 + "/" + d3 + "/" + d5;
        service_Date = d5 + "-" + d3 + "-" + d4;
    }
    else
    {
        date = "";
        service_Date = "";
    }

    string dt2 = txtToDate.Text;
    string t1, t5 = "", t3 = "", t4 = "", d2, t6, serv;
    if (dt1 != "")
    {
        t1 = dt2;
        if (t1.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] word = t1.Split('.');
            t5 = word[0];
            t3 = word[1];
            t4 = word[2];
        }
        else if (t1.Contains("-"))
        {
            string[] word = t1.Split('-');
            t5 = word[0];
            t3 = word[1];
            t4 = word[2];
        }
        else if (t1.Contains("/"))
        {
            string[] word = t1.Split('/');
            t5 = word[0];
            t3 = word[1];
            t4 = word[2];
        }


        d2 = t4 + "/" + t3 + "/" + t5;
        serv = t5 + "-" + t3 + "-" + t4;
        //d5 = d3 + "/" + d6 + "/" + d4 ;
    }
    else
    {
        d2 = "";
        serv = "";
    }
    dttest.Columns.Add("MACHINENAME_DATE");
    ArrayList Array_machine = new ArrayList();
    using (con = new SqlConnection(con_str))
    {
        con.Open();
        string qry;

        qry = "select distinct mname from tb_reqmach  where fromdate>='" + date + "' and todate<='" + d2 + "' and mcfact='" + drpfact.Text + "' group by mname  ";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Array_machine.Add(dr["mname"].ToString().Trim());
            //dttest.Rows.Add();
            dttest.Rows.Add(dr["mname"].ToString().Trim());
        }

        con.Close();
    }

    ArrayList Array_L = new ArrayList();
    DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
    Array_L.Add(startDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
    dttest.Columns.Add(startDate.ToShortDateString());
    DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(d2);
    while (startDate < endDate)
    {

        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
        Array_L.Add(startDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
        dttest.Columns.Add(startDate.ToShortDateString());
    }


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    int m = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < Array_L.Count; j++)
    {
        int avail = 0;
        int planned = 0;
        int req = 0;

        for (int d = 0; d < Array_machine.Count; d++)
        {
            //dttest.Columns.Add();
            //  dttest.Columns.Add();
            //  xlworksheet.Cells[4 + d, 1] = Array_machine[d];
            // dttest.Rows.Add();
            string machine_name = Array_machine[d].ToString();
            string Date = Array_L[j].ToString();
            // xlworksheet.Cells[3, m + 2] = Date;



            //DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
            //keyColumns[0] = dttest.Columns["MACHINENAME/DATE"];
            //dttest.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;
            //if (dttest.Rows.Contains(machine_name))
            //{
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //dttest.Rows.Add(machine_name);
            //}
            //   dttest.Rows[d][1] = Array_machine[d];

            // [xlworksheet].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            //    xlworksheet.Range["A3", m + 2].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#99CCFF");
            //  dt.Columns.Add(machine_name);
            using (con = new SqlConnection(con_str))
            {

                con.Open();
                string qry1;

                //qry = "select distinct mname from tb_reqmach where mcfact='" + drpfact.Text + "' group by mname ";
                qry1 = "select count(mcdesp) as mcdesp from machine where mcdesp='" + Array_machine[d].ToString().Trim() + "' and mcfact='" + drpfact.Text + "' ";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(qry1, con);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    // xlworksheet.Cells[dtcount + 1, m + 7] = dr["mcdesp"].ToString().Trim();
                    avail = Convert.ToInt32(dr["mcdesp"].ToString().Trim());
                }
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                string qry;

                qry = "SELECT sum(rmachine) as mname FROM tb_reqmach WHERE '" + Array_L[j].ToString() + "' BETWEEN fromdate AND todate and mname='" + Array_machine[d].ToString().Trim() + "' and mcfact='" + drpfact.Text + "'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    //  dttest.Rows.Add();
                    //xlworksheet.Columns[i].ColumnWidth = 18;
                    //  xlworksheet.Cells[d + 4, 2 + m] = dr["mname"].ToString().Trim();
                    dttest.Rows[d][j + 1] = dr["mname"].ToString().Trim();
                    if (dr["mname"].ToString().Trim() != "")
                    {
                        planned = Convert.ToInt32(dr["mname"].ToString().Trim());
                        req = avail - planned;
                        int rows = d + 4;
                        int cols = 2 + m;
                        // string rowA = FindResA(rows);
                        // string colB = FindResB(cols);
                        if (req < 0)
                        {
                            // xlworksheet.Range[colB + rows, colB + rows].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff0000");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //  xlworksheet.Range[colB + rows, colB + rows].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#008000");
                        }
                    }

                    //  dttest.Rows[d][m+1] = dr["mname"].ToString().Trim();
                    // xlworksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
                    // gvtest.HeaderRow.Cells(d).Text = dr["mname"].ToString().Trim();
                    //dt.Rows.Add();
                    // dt.Rows[d][machine_name] = dr["mname"].ToString().Trim();
                }

                con.Close();

            }

        }
        m++;
        //    gvtest.DataSource = dt;
        //  gvtest.DataBind();
        //ID = (i + 1).ToString();
        //  string machine_name = Array_machine[j].ToString();
        // xlworksheet.Cells[4 + i, 1] = ID;
        //  xlworksheet.Cells[4 + i, 2] = machine_name;
        // xlworksheet.Cells[3, m + 2] = machine_name;
        // 
    }

    Session["dttest"] = dttest;
    GridView4.DataSource = dttest;
    GridView4.DataBind();






    for (int j = 0; j < Array_L.Count; j++)
    {
        int avail = 0;
        int planned = 0;
        int req = 0;

        for (int d = 0; d < Array_machine.Count; d++)
        {
            //dttest.Columns.Add();
            //  dttest.Columns.Add();
            //  xlworksheet.Cells[4 + d, 1] = Array_machine[d];
            // dttest.Rows.Add();
            string machine_name = Array_machine[d].ToString();
            string Date = Array_L[j].ToString();
            // xlworksheet.Cells[3, m + 2] = Date;



            //DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
            //keyColumns[0] = dttest.Columns["MACHINENAME/DATE"];
            //dttest.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;
            //if (dttest.Rows.Contains(machine_name))
            //{
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //dttest.Rows.Add(machine_name);
            //}
            //   dttest.Rows[d][1] = Array_machine[d];

            // [xlworksheet].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
            //    xlworksheet.Range["A3", m + 2].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#99CCFF");
            //  dt.Columns.Add(machine_name);
            using (con = new SqlConnection(con_str))
            {

                con.Open();
                string qry1;

                //qry = "select distinct mname from tb_reqmach where mcfact='" + drpfact.Text + "' group by mname ";
                qry1 = "select count(mcdesp) as mcdesp from machine where mcdesp='" + Array_machine[d].ToString().Trim() + "' and mcfact='" + drpfact.Text + "' ";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(qry1, con);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    // xlworksheet.Cells[dtcount + 1, m + 7] = dr["mcdesp"].ToString().Trim();
                    avail = Convert.ToInt32(dr["mcdesp"].ToString().Trim());
                }
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                string qry;

                qry = "SELECT sum(rmachine) as mname FROM tb_reqmach WHERE '" + Array_L[j].ToString() + "' BETWEEN fromdate AND todate and mname='" + Array_machine[d].ToString().Trim() + "' and mcfact='" + drpfact.Text + "'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    //  dttest.Rows.Add();
                    //xlworksheet.Columns[i].ColumnWidth = 18;
                    //  xlworksheet.Cells[d + 4, 2 + m] = dr["mname"].ToString().Trim();
                    // dttest.Rows[d][j + 1] = dr["mname"].ToString().Trim();
                    if (dr["mname"].ToString().Trim() != "")
                    {
                        planned = Convert.ToInt32(dr["mname"].ToString().Trim());
                        req = avail - planned;
                        int rows = d + 4;
                        int cols = 2 + m;
                        // string rowA = FindResA(rows);
                        // string colB = FindResB(cols);
                        if (req < 0)
                        {
                            GridView4.Rows[d].Cells[j + 1].BackColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }

                }

                con.Close();

            }

        }
        m++;

    }


    foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView4.Rows)
    {
        // LinkButton hp = new LinkButton();
        for (int k = 1; k < dttest.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            LinkButton hp = new LinkButton();
            if (gr.Cells[k].Text != "")
            {
                hp.Text = gr.Cells[k].Text;
                //defsur_Click(sender, e);
                //GridViewRow gvr = e.Row;
                //var rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
                //Label username = (Label)GridView3.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("machinename");
                //mcname = username.Text;
                // hp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "Gridview4_linkclick");
                hp.Click += new EventHandler(Gridview4_linkclick);
                // hp.NavigateUrl = "~/Default.aspx?name=" + hp.Text;
                gr.Cells[k].Controls.Add(hp);
            }
        }

    }
    GridView4.Columns[0].Visible = false;'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet. It loops all the cells in the row the clicked button is in and tries to find the correct column.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //get the control that fired the method
    Control control = e.CommandSource as Control;

    //get the row containing the control
    GridViewRow gvr = control.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    //get the row number
    int rowNumber = gvr.RowIndex;

    //declare the column variable
    int columnNumber = -1;

    //loop all the columns in the gridview
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        //try to find the button that was clicked in each individual cell
        Button button = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[i].FindControl(control.ID) as Button;

        //if the button is found set the column number
        if (button != null)
        {
            columnNumber = i;
        }
    }

    //get the column name
    Label1.Text = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[columnNumber].Text;
}
```

GridView example

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: LinkButton button = GridView4.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[i].FindControl(control.ID) as LinkButton;

Comment: In (control.ID)  ID returns null

Comment: control has value 25

Comment: See my GridView example

Comment: That's a lot of code, but it looks like you are not assigning an `ID` to LinkButton `hp`. `hp.ID = "LinkButton_" + k;`

Comment: '<asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server"  IOnRowDataBound="GridView4_RowDataBound" 
 AutoGenerateColumns="true" onrowcommand="GridView4_RowCommand">                            <Columns> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MACHINENAME_DATE">                                    <EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="machinename" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("MACHINENAME_DATE") %>'></asp:Label> </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField></Columns>
 </asp:GridView>'

Comment: Not related to this, but I see you've asked questions in the past but never accepted an answer as the correct one. If an answer is correct you should mark it as such to help others.

Comment: Label1.Text = GridView4.HeaderRow.Cells[columnNumber].Text;  it returns error now

Comment: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index

Comment: I m new to this site and a new developer i dont know how to accept as answer.

Comment: gridview.columns,count is always returning 1

Comment: Did you change `Button` to `LinkButton` in `Button button = GridView1.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[i].FindControl(control.ID) as Button;`

Comment: Yaa.because i used link button in gridview.

Comment: And dynamically created controls need to be created EVERY TIME the page is loaded, and that includes a PostBack. So the loop to add buttons must not be inside a `if (!IsPostBack) { }`

Comment: ya..added..bt your code is not working properly,its always retrieve the last button column name