# getting gridview cell in other method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with editable rows and had a dropdown in one column

in dropdown_selectedindexchanged,

is there any way to get value of selected dropdown value of selected row in dropdown_selectedindexchanged

i think, explained it right

Thanks

Comment: did you searched at all before posting the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. Just cast the `sender` back to the original Control.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;

    Label1.Text = ddl.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Wow!! and it will throw a `NullRefException` since not checked for null

Comment: No it won't since there is always a `sender`

Comment: but it may not be `dropdownlist`

Comment: Theoretically yes, but you would normally attach it to the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of a `DropDownList` Control. As OP wrote in his question.

Comment: Thanks i got the value of dropdown, is there a way to get control of remaining cells in same row

Comment: Use the NaminContainer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056942/how-to-get-header-name-in-autogenerated-gridview